# Make MariaDB 10.3 on raspberry pi use OpenSSL instead of yaSSL

Tags: raspberry-pi, openssl, mariadb, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

I have a raspberry pi setup using Raspbian Buster and created an OpenSSL Certificate Authority I intend to use with a mobile app. The root CA signs an intermediate CA that signs the server certificate for a MariaDB MySql server and using a self-made WebAPI, it can sign certificate signing requests for clients to access the DB (clients and the server must both be authenticated).

I can connect to the database over the MariaDB client, using SSL and requiring the client to authenticate its certificate, however if I revoke the client certificate it still allows access. It appears that on the Raspberry Pi, MariaDB runs 10.3 and uses the yaSSL library instead of OpenSSL, even though the OpenSSL library is on the Pi.

Is there a way I can make MariaDB use OpenSSL rather than yaSSL as openSSL supports crl_path, which is required for mariadb to check the revocation list and deny access to revoked certificates as explained [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/secure-connections-overview/#certificate-revocation-lists-crls). Another option would be to use MariaDB 10.4 however I believe it must be compiled from source which i tried to no avail, or use another OS which I would not like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm attempting to do the same but using 10.5 stable released source. It's currently compiling ...

There is a build configuration switch that cmake needs to make it compile with openssl: cmake  -DWITH_SSL=SYSTEM

That will make the make use the OS provided SSL library which in my case on Raspberry Pi4 Raspbian Buster 64 bit is openssl.

After you run cmake you can double check by running cmake  -LH which should show openssl in the list.

(Yeah, I've no idea who made the bright decision to disable SSL on mariadb for raspbian buster !)

Comment: Ah right to be honest I was struggling to get this to work as it never seemed to want to compile, so in the end i switched distros. I chose manjaro arm since it had the latest version i needed and is relatively easy to use, did lose vnc though which is much easier on raspbian. Once I did that I could set it all up quite easily, so if you arent super invested in raspbian you could always try it.